# WaitForSingleObject for thread object does not work in DLL unload

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, dll

I've stumbled upon an unexpected behavior of Windows thread mechanism when DLL is unloaded. A have a pack of worker thread objects and I'm trying to finish them graciously when DLL is unloaded (via DllMain DLL_PROCESS_DETACH). The code is very simple (I do send an event to finish the thread's wait loop):

```
WaitForSingleObject( ThrHandle, INFINITE );
CloseHandle( ThrHandle );
```

Yet the WaitForSingleObject hangs the whole thing. It works fine if I perform it before DLL is unloaded. How this behavior can be fixed?

Comment: Deadlock inside DllMain() is a very common problem.  If this code you are waiting on does anything to get another DLL unloaded then the loader lock will always hang your program.  Use the debugger to diagnose this.  Something you should already have done to document this question, like posting the call stack of that thread.  The long and short of it is that waiting for *anything* in DllMain() is dangerous and should always be avoided.

Comment: No, deadlock is impossible. All the worker thread does is wait for an event. WaitForSingleObject( Event, INFINITE ); Which I send before calling the  WaitForSingleObject( ThrHandle, INFINITE )

Comment: Sounds like you don't know what "loader lock" means, you are waiting for *two* sync objects.  If they don't get signaled in the right order then you deadlock.  Googles well.

Comment: No, that's not the case. I'll repeat that problem does not happen if I call the same code outside of the DLL unload call.

Comment: Well, of course not, the loader lock is not held.  Insisting that you don't have a problem doesn't help us help you, post that stack trace.

Comment: Stack trace? Are you asking it for the sake of asking it? What is purpose of it? It's not a crash, it's a hangup of WaitForSingleObject() function. There's no use in stack trace.

Comment: Yes stack traces are really only ever useful in case of crashes and have no use whatsoever when analysing deadlocks, well except if you know what you're doing then they can be tremendously helpful. Honestly, be less aggressive and listen to the advise of people like Hans who are way more experienced than you. It's almost certainly the loader lock.

Comment: Since you feel you know more than we do, why are you asking?

Comment: DllMain calls are serialized. When the worker thread exits, it tries to send the DLL_THREAD_DETACH notification, but it can't do that until your DLL_PROCESS_DETACH completes. Hence the deadlock. You need to invent a function in your DLL for the app to call before it unloads the DLL. That function can shut down the worker threads.

Comment: @aleksv: Raymond even described this on [his blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283): "*This deadlock is much more commonly seen in DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, where a DLL wants to shut down its worker threads and wait for them to clean up before it unloads itself. **You can’t wait for a thread inside DLL_PROCESS_DETACH** because that thread needs to send out the DLL_THREAD_DETACH notifications before it exits, which it can’t do until your DLL_PROCESS_DETACH handler returns.*"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[You can't wait for a thread to exit in DllMain().](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283)  Unless the thread had already exited by the time the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH was received, doing so will *always* deadlock.  This is the expected behaviour.

The reason for this is that calls to DllMain() are serialized, via the loader lock.  When ExitThread() is called, it claims the loader lock so that it can call DllMain() with DLL_THREAD_DETACH.  Until that call has finished, the thread is still running.

So DllMain is waiting for the thread to exit, and the thread is waiting for DllMain to exit, a classic deadlock situation.

See also [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx) on MSDN.

**The solution is to add a new function to your DLL for the application to call before unloading the DLL.**  As you have noted, your code already works perfectly well when called explicitly.

---

In the case where backwards compatibility requirements make adding such a function impossible, and if you *must* have the worker threads, consider splitting your DLL into two parts, one of which is dynamically loaded by the other.  The dynamically loaded part would contain (at a minimum) all of the code needed by the worker threads.

When the DLL that was loaded by the application itself receives DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, you just set the event to signal the threads to exit and then return immediately.  One of the threads would have to be designated to wait for all the others and then free the second DLL, which you can do safely using [FreeLibraryAndExitThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683153(v=vs.85).aspx).

(Depending on the circumstances, and in particular if worker threads are exiting and/or new ones being created as part of regular operations, you may need to be very careful to avoid race conditions and/or deadlocks; this would likely be simpler if you used a thread pool and callbacks rather than creating worker threads manually.)

---

**In the special case** where the threads do not need to use any but the very simplest Windows APIs, it might be possible to use a thread pool and work callbacks to avoid the need for a second DLL.  Once the callbacks have exited, which you can check using [WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687053(v=vs.85).aspx), it is safe for the library to be unloaded - you do not need to wait for the threads themselves to exit.

The catch here is that the callbacks must avoid any Windows APIs that might take the loader lock.  It is not documented which API calls are safe in this respect, and it varies between different versions of Windows.  If you are calling anything more complicated than SetEvent or WriteFile, say, or if you are using a library rather than native Windows API functions, you **must not** use this approach.

Comment: Link to official documentation: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx).

Comment: [Not always](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant: you mean, the application might have disabled thread notifications for every DLL, including the C runtime library?  [Technically correct I suppose.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo). :-)

Comment: You have no idea how much this helped me. +1

Answer (score 0):

I have such problem when I try to inject code into another desktop process, WaitForSingleObject will cause the deadlock inside my thread. I solved the issue by trapping the window's default message procedure, hope it helps for others.

```
#define WM_INSIDER  (WM_USER + 2021)
WNDPROC prev_proc = nullptr;

HWND FindTopWindow(DWORD pid)
{   
    struct Find { HWND win; DWORD pid; } find = { nullptr, pid };

    EnumWindows([](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL {
        auto p = (Find*)(lParam);
        DWORD id;
        if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &id) && id == p->pid) {
            // done
            p->win = hwnd;
            return FALSE;
        }
        // continue
        return TRUE;
    }, (LPARAM)&find);

    return find.win;
}

// thread entry
int insider(void *)
{
    // do whatever you want as a normal thread
    return (0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK insider_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HANDLE t;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_INSIDER:
        t = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)insider, 0, 0, NULL);
        CloseHandle(t);
        break;
    }

    return CallWindowProc(prev_proc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void setup() {
    auto pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
    auto win = FindTopWindow(pid);
    prev_proc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(win, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&insider_proc);
    // signal to create thread later    
    PostMessage(win, WM_INSIDER, 0, 0);
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:        
        setup();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:     
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:     
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:            
        break;
    }   
    return TRUE;
}
```